# ASP.NET Core - Authorize attribute doesn't force redirect to login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, asp.net-core, authorize

I have setup a new asp.NET Core web project. I want to have custom authentication, where I create my own cookie and assign claims to the user.  This was fairly straight forward to setup.

My Startup.cs code looks like this:

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
            .AddEnvironmentVariables();
        Configuration = builder.Build();
    }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        services.Configure<CookieAuthenticationOptions>(options =>
        {
            options.LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login");
            options.AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/account/accessdenied");
            options.AutomaticChallenge = true;
        });

        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
           options.AddPolicy("AdminOnly", policy => {  
               policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"); });
           });
        }
    
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, 
                              IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {

        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            LoginPath = new PathString("/account/login"),
            AccessDeniedPath = new PathString("/account/accessdenied"),
            AutomaticChallenge = true
        });

        app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
    }
}
```

I then set the following logon method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Login(string userName, 
           string password, string returnUrl = null)
{
        ViewData["ReturnUrl"] = returnUrl;

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userName) && userName == password)
        {
            List<Claim> claims;

            switch (userName)
            {

                case "admin":
                    claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("sub", "2"),
                        new Claim("name", "Bob"),
                        new Claim("email", "bob@smith.com"),
                        new Claim("status", "junior"),
                        new Claim("department", "sales"),
                        new Claim("region", "north"),
                        new Claim("role", "supervisor"),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin")
                    };
                    break;
                    
                default:
                    claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim("sub", "3"),
                        new Claim("name", userName),
                        new Claim("email", userName + "@smith.com"),
                        new Claim("status", "intern"),
                        new Claim("department", "development"),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "client")
                    };
                    break;
            }

            var id = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "local");//, "local", "name", "role"
                    await HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync("Cookies", 
                new ClaimsPrincipal(id));
    
            return LocalRedirect("/Home/Index");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

All works fine, and putting the [Authorize] attribute on any of the controller methods, stops access unless you are logged in, like so:

```
    [Authorize]
    public IActionResult AccessibleToLoggedIn()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Example - open to any logged in user!";
        return View();
    }

    [Authorize(Policy ="AdminOnly")]
    public IActionResult AdminPage()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Admin only page";
        return View();
    }
```

All sounds good so far...

One thing I'm struggling to get working - when a user attempts to access the view with the [Authorize] attribute attached, they don't get redirected to the login page.

What am I doing wrong?

I would also like to be able to redirect a user to an access denied page later on, when they don't match a particular policy I intend to define.

Thanks in advance for any pointers!

Comment: Are you running on IIS Express?

Comment: I am!  And as soon as you said that, I tried running via NodeJs and it worked!  Ok - so what's the difference here.  In the end my application will most likely be hosted in windows and on IIS.  How do I make this work in that scenario also?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/41161634/1625737

Comment: Updating all packages (from 1.0.1 to 1.1.0) at first yielded this error "The project does not list one of 'win10-x64, win81-x64, win7-x64' in the 'runtimes'".  See this article to fix: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37590604/can-not-find-runtime-target-for-framework-netcoreapp-v1-compatible-with-one-of     after this, the project compiled fine and IIS Express redirects as expected.

Comment: great! having exact *opposite** problem :-/